# Laravel Like Eloquent with array value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

How can I do a Like-query, with multiple values to search for?

```
$searchWords = explode(' ', Input::get('search'));
```

Then I get an array of words that were given for the search.

How can I pass it in this:

```
$pages = Page::where('content', 'LIKE', '%'.$singleWord.'%')->distinct()->get();
```

A loop can't work, then it overwrites the $pages always; then it keeps always the latest search:

```
foreach($searchWords as $word){
    $pages = Page::where('content', 'LIKE', '%'.$word.'%')->distinct()->get();
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A loop is the solution but you only need to add the where condition without executing the query

```
$pages = Page::query();
foreach($searchWords as $word){
    $pages->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%'.$word.'%');
}
$pages = $pages->distinct()->get();
```

Comment: Can you use `->toSql()` instead of `->get()` and show me the return value?

Comment: It works, you must be using keyword that returns all pages, that's all.

Comment: added trim() to the searchword ;-)

Comment: `trim() `is the key to haven.

Answer (score 8):

i will code it for you :

```
$pages = Page->where(function($query) use($word){

foreach($searchWords as $word){
    $query->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%'.$word.'%');
}

})->get();
```

you can try that , i hope that will help :)