# How to Make Solutions for Arrays to String Conversions?

Tags: php, laravel, sum, laravel-query-builder, laravel-5.7

[image: Screenshot]

#### Model

> "Array to string conversion (SQL: update `spent_times` set `updated_at` = 2018-10-18 07:20:22, `spent_time` = 12, `percentage` = 60.00, `task_category` = testing where `id` = 7) ◀"

```
<?php

public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $fromDate = Carbon::now()->subDay()->startOfWeek()->toDateString();
    $nowDate = Carbon::now()->today()->toDateString();

    $spent_time = static::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();

    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    } else {

        $new_spent_time = SpentTime::find($plan_id);
        $task_category = $new_spent_time->task_category;

        $new_spent_time->task_category = (['{task_category}' => $task_category,
            '{daily_spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time,
            '{daily_percentage}' => $new_spent_time->daily_percentage,
            '{spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->spent_time,
            '{percentage}' => $new_spent_time->percentage]);

        $new_spent_time->spent_time = $new_spent_time::where('task_category', 'LIKE', (array)"%$task_category%")
            ->sum('daily_spent_time', 'LIKE', (array)"%$new_spent_time->daily_spent_time%", $fromDate);
        $request['spent_time'] = (int)$new_spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

        $new_spent_time->percentage = $new_spent_time::where('task_category', 'LIKE', (array)"%$spent_time->task_category%")
            ->sum('daily_percentage', 'LIKE', (array)"%$new_spent_time->daily_percentage%", $fromDate);
        $request['percentage'] = (int)$new_spent_time->percentage + $spent_time->daily_percentage;
        $new_spent_time->save();

        return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `$task_category` inside `"%$task_category%"` array?

If so, it cause error because array cannot be put %.

This may be the solution for **laravel**c [Like with array value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696212/laravel-like-eloquent-with-array-value)

---

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_spent_time->spent_time = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_spent_time', $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time , $fromDate);
$request['spent_time'] = (int)$new_spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

$new_spent_time->percentage = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$spent_time->task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_percentage', $new_spent_time->daily_percentage, $fromDate);
$request['percentage'] = (int)$new_spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return updated query so try

```
return $spent_time->fresh();
```

and then the error persists add as

```
return $spent_time->fresh()->toArray();
```

Comment: @Lianurfadilah I cannot get you? So can you explain me

Comment: you can see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889490/how-to-calculate-data-by-category-when-creating-new-data-with-the-same-category/52890721#52890721

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922240/cant-save-calcution-data-when-create-new-data?noredirect=1#comment92754604_52922240

Comment: Alter toArray() to toJson() method

Comment: Try return response()->json($spent_time->fresh()->toArray());

Comment: there is still no change