# Laravel Eloquent for where Like

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to filter account in laravel.1 user can have many accounts with different format. It doesnt seem to work.The query:

```
$accounts = $user->account()->where('account_no','like', ['34%','35%','3303%','3304%'])->get();
```

i'm wondering if this can be done or not?

Comment: Sorry i just edit the post. it suppose for condition where like

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696212/laravel-like-eloquent-with-array-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this workaround :

```
$checks = array('34','35','3304','3305');  

$accounts = $user->accounts()            
    ->Where(function ($query) use($checks) {
         foreach ($checks as $check){
            $query->orwhere('account_no', 'like', $check .'%');
         }      
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. For each condition you need a single WHERE condition, like this:

```
$accounts = $user->account()->where('account_no','like','34%')
  ->orWhere('account_no','like','35%')
  ->orWhere('account_no','like','3303%')
  ->orWhere('account_no','like','3304%')
  ->get();
```

That should do it.

Comment: kindly, avoid adding duplicate answers for duplicate questions :)

Comment: The question isn't marked as a duplicate, though.

Comment: Not market, yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it by `RAW Query`,
Like this:

```
$accounts = $user->account()->whereRaw("account_no like ('34%','35%','3303%','3304%') ")->get();
```